# Create an index of PDF files selectable from icloud

Tags: icloud

I have a group of around 50 PDF files with related stuff.  My goal is to have a select list so I can open the relevant one without scrolling through a list of file names.

This was easy enough on macOS, i just created an HTML document with a bunch of anchor links.

I uploaded all the files to icloud.  And the Files app on iOS will render the HTML file.  But clicking on the links does not do anything.  Obviously I'd like it to launch the PDF viewer.

Does anyone know how to make this work on iOS?

Comment: Can you give an example of an “anchor link”? I’m guessing you mean like “file://“. Either way unless you find a PDF app with a URL Scheme like “pdf://“ I don’t think you can do what you want. You would also need to know the location of the file within iOS’s file system which is difficult without a jailbroken device.

Comment: Yes I mean html <a>  Oddly I didn't try putting a protocol on it.  Or a path.  So that was kind of stupid.  Putting pdf:// it doesn't do anything.  Putting file:// it opens safari which disappointingly refuses to render.  I saw some related posts that talked about WORKFLOW.  This seems to be Apple's version of IFTTT.  I never liked IFTTT.  Workflow seems probably good but doesn't do what I want.  I'd hoped moving the files to iCloud I could get around the "inter-app security".

Comment: All the files are only 70MB which I suppose isn't really THAT big.  Unless a better answer pops up I will just combine them all and use a PDF Table of Contents.  In other news every PDF viewer app I've ever had is worse than the one before.  Amazing if you think about it.